# Gazebo Classic - Inertia Visual Does not Match Robot Shape

Tags: ros, gazebo-11

With the following values, the inertia visual in Gazebo 11 matches the basic shape. (inertia implementation at bottom of post)

```
   <xacro:property name="m1" value="13.0"/>
   <xacro:property name="l1" value="0.80"/>
```

[image]
Changing length slightly (this is after trial and error to find the crossover point) the inertia visual is larger than the link shape.

```
  <xacro:property name="m1" value="13.0"/>
  <xacro:property name="l1" value="0.70"/>
```

[image]
Why is this happening? Also, is this hinting that the inertia in simulation is reflective of the larger shape, or the numerical values I've input?

My code for calculating inertia matrix

```
   <link name="$(arg namespace)/prime_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <mass value="${m1}"/>
        <inertia
          ixx="${m1 / 12 * (l1 * l1 + l1 * l1)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="${m1 / 12 * (l1 * l1 + l1 * l1)}" iyz="0.0"
          izz="${m1 / 12 * (l1 * l1 + l1 * l1)}"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${l1} ${l1} ${l1}"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.027 0.027 0.027"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
```